# both textview show value on same location how do i change or space inbetween them?

Tags: android

in my barcode xml result file both text view show result on samre location and overlap each other how do i make space in between them?? i try android_layout gravity=center or left rightr is not work only this work  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_view"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



<com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView
  android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:background="@color/transparent"/>


<TextView android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="hello"      
        android:textSize="14sp"/>


  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResult2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="aaaa" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"


    android:text="View Detail" />





    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your 2 TextView and Button inside a LinearLayout with orientation vertical. And 1 more point, When using FrameLayout, don't forget to add the attribute layout_gravity in your code.

Comment: i try it 2nd test view like this

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:text="aaaa" />

Comment: now is gos on top right side in screen but to much space in between to tet view

   textvie11-----------------------textview2

how i remove space between them?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview_view"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>



<com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView
  android:id="@+id/viewfinder_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"

  android:background="@color/transparent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtResult"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtResult2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="aaaa" />
    </LinearLayout>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"


    android:text="View Detail" />





    </FrameLayout>
```

put the textview like the way above ....

Answer (score 0):

Inherit `ViewfinderView` from `RelativeLayout` and use `layout_toRightOf`, `layout_toLeftOf`, `layout_below` or `layout_above`, whatever you need.

```
<com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtResult2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtResult"/>

</com.zijunlin.Zxing.Demo.view.ViewfinderView>
```